# Why is this code to create an archive page not working on this blog?

Tags: html, css, blogger, blogspot

I've been creating a new lay-out for a friend's blogspot on a test blog. I've tried to create an archive page by using this code over here: https://github.com/jhwilson/Create-a-Blogger-archive-page. Somehow this doesn't work when I add it to this page: http://starttofashiontest.blogspot.be/p/archive.html. I've also tried to add an archive like this: gadgetsappshacks.com/2011/09/creating-automatic-archive-page-in.html, but it doesn't work either. It would be really nice if someone could help me out!

```
    <b:widget id='BlogArchive1' locked='false' title='' type='BlogArchive'>
              <b:includable id='main'>
  <b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
    <h2><data:title/></h2>
  </b:if>
  <div class='widget-content'>
  <div id='ArchiveList'>
  <div expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_ArchiveList&quot;'>
    <b:include cond='data:style == &quot;HIERARCHY&quot;' data='data' name='interval'/>
    <b:include cond='data:style == &quot;FLAT&quot;' data='data' name='flat'/>
    <b:include cond='data:style == &quot;MENU&quot;' data='data' name='menu'/>
  </div>
  </div>
  <b:include name='quickedit'/>
  </div>
</b:includable>
              <b:includable id='flat' var='data'>
  <ul class='flat'>
    <b:loop values='data:data' var='i'>
      <li class='archivedate'>
        <a expr:href='data:i.url'><data:i.name/></a> (<data:i.post-count/>)
      </li>
    </b:loop>
  </ul>
</b:includable>
              <b:includable id='interval' var='intervalData'>
  <b:loop values='data:intervalData' var='interval'>
    <ul class='hierarchy'>
      <li expr:class='&quot;archivedate &quot; + data:interval.expclass'>
        <b:include cond='data:interval.toggleId' data='interval' name='toggle'/>
        <a class='post-count-link' expr:href='data:interval.url'>
          <data:interval.name/>
        </a>
        <span class='post-count' dir='ltr'>(<data:interval.post-count/>)</span>
        <b:include cond='data:interval.data' data='interval.data' name='interval'/>
        <b:include cond='data:interval.posts' data='interval.posts' name='posts'/>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </b:loop>
</b:includable>
              <b:includable id='menu' var='data'>
  <select expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_ArchiveMenu&quot;'>
    <option value=''><data:title/></option>
    <b:loop values='data:data' var='i'>
      <option expr:value='data:i.url'><data:i.name/> (<data:i.post-count/>)</option>
    </b:loop>
  </select>
</b:includable>
              <b:includable id='posts' var='posts'>
  <ul class='posts'>
    <b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
      <li><a expr:href='data:post.url'><data:post.title/></a></li>
    </b:loop>
  </ul>
</b:includable>
              <b:includable id='toggle' var='interval'>
  <a class='toggle' href='javascript:void(0)'>
    <span expr:class='&quot;zippy&quot; + (data:interval.expclass == &quot;expanded&quot; ? &quot; toggle-open&quot; : &quot;&quot;)'>
      <b:if cond='data:interval.expclass == &quot;expanded&quot;'>
        &#9660;&#160;
      <b:elseif cond='data:blog.languageDirection == &quot;rtl&quot;'/>
        &#9668;&#160;
      <b:else/>
        &#9658;&#160;
      </b:if>
    </span>
  </a>
</b:includable>
            </b:widget>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? I can see it works.

Comment: Please add all of the code needed to understand the question to the body of the question.

Comment: @PraveenKumar  The archive that is visible is a standard widget I've added to test out this code: http://www.gadgetsappshacks.com/2011/09/creating-automatic-archive-page-in.html. The problem is that, when I add that code, the widget stays visible on all pages and therefore the code does not work.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth I wasn't completely sure which parts to add, but I guess the code of the widget itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to display archive page, paste in html mode of a page:

```
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
<h2 style="text-align: left;">
Full Archive of YourSite</h2>
<div id="bp_toc">
<script src="http://bloggergadgets.googlecode.com/files/blogtoc_orig.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script src="/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json-in-script&amp;max-results=500&amp;callback=loadtoc" type="text/javascript">
</script>



<style>
#bp_toc {
border: 5px solid #c1bfbf;
padding: 5px;
width:100%;
margin-top:10px;
}
.toc-header-col1, .toc-header-col2, .toc-header-col3 {
background: #fff;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 5px;
width:60%;
}
.toc-header-col2 {
width:20%;
}
.toc-header-col3 {
width:20%;
}
.toc-header-col1 a:link, .toc-header-col1 a:visited, .toc-header-col2 a:link, .toc-header-col2 a:visited, .toc-header-col3 a:link, .toc-header-col3 a:visited {
font-size:18px;
text-decoration:none;
}
.toc-header-col1 a:hover, .toc-header-col2 a:hover, .toc-header-col3 a:hover {
font-size:18px;
text-decoration:underline;
}
.toc-entry-col1, .toc-entry-col2, .toc-entry-col3 {
padding-left: 5px;
font-size:18px;
}
</style>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, it works! Thank you so much!